# Export all data to excel from this website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

i'm a newbie in webscrapping and i need to do a code to export all data to excel from this website

to excel. without filtering or filtering every possibilities.

i have got the error

> method "queryselector" of object "jscripttypeinfo" failed

```
Sub CartaSocial()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim tipoEntidade, tipoEntidadeAtual, areaGeo, areaGeoAtual, pesquisa As Object
Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
Dim arrTipoEntidade, arrAreaGeo As Variant

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

' Navegar para a página inicial
ie.Navigate "https://www.cartasocial.pt/"

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop


Set tipoEntidade = ie.document.querySelector("#_SocialLetterHomePortlet_WAR_cartasocialportlet_:form:entType_input").getElementsByTagName("option")
arrTipoEntidade = Array()
For i = 0 To tipoEntidade.Length - 1
    ReDim Preserve arrTipoEntidade(i)
    arrTipoEntidade(i) = tipoEntidade(i).Value
Next i


Set areaGeo = ie.document.querySelector("#_SocialLetterHomePortlet_WAR_cartasocialportlet_:form:distrito_input").getElementsByTagName("option")
arrAreaGeo = Array()
For j = 0 To areaGeo.Length - 1
    ReDim Preserve arrAreaGeo(j)
    arrAreaGeo(j) = areaGeo(j).Value
Next j


Set pesquisa = ie.document.querySelector("#_SocialLetterHomePortlet_WAR_cartasocialportlet_:form:searchEntity_button")

For k = 0 To UBound(arrTipoEntidade)
    ' Selecionar o tipo de entidade
    Set tipoEntidadeAtual = tipoEntidade(k)
    tipoEntidadeAtual.Selected = True
    
    For l = 0 To UBound(arrAreaGeo)
        ' Selecionar a área geográfica
        Set areaGeoAtual = areaGeo(l)
        areaGeoAtual.Selected = True
        
        pesquisa.Click
        

        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        
    
        ie.Navigate "https://www.cartasocial.pt/"
        
      
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    Next l
Next k


ie.Quit

End Sub
```

some details in code.
i have microsoft office 2013 pt. Is necessary some driver? like selenium or something else?

tks

Comment: i have got the error "method "queryselector" of object "jscripttypeinfo" failed

Comment: So you have some code. If you need help with your code, you would need to include that in your question.

Comment: Done @braX tks for your help